# Azure Web app Error: Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' (x86) was not found

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

i am deploying my Asp.net core app to azure web app using azure devops pipelines.
here is my csproj Prepertygroup :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
     <Version>3.1.18</Version>
    <!--<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>-->
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet-81EA87AD-E64D-4755-A1CC-5EA47F49B5D8</UserSecretsId>
    <WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>0</WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Using this pipeline script to deploy to azure Web app Windows with a .NET version : .NET Core 3.1/2.1.

```
 trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

 
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: '5.0.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions
    performMultiLevelLookup: true
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
   version: '3.1.x'
   packageType: sdk
   includePreviewVersions: true
   performMultiLevelLookup: true
```

Everything deploys, but when i start the application i get this error :
[image]

when i go to see the logs here is what i find :

```
Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message:
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' (x86) was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x86&rid=win10-x86
```

Any ideas ? To be honest i am a little confused with the difference between the .netcore versions required on the azure web app and the one i used .netcore3.1.

Edit "1" :
Here is my csproj file :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    
<WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>0</WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="AppCreationScripts\**" />
    <Compile Remove="ReadmeFiles\**" />
    <Content Remove="AppCreationScripts\**" />
    <Content Remove="ReadmeFiles\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="AppCreationScripts\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="ReadmeFiles\**" />
    <None Remove="AppCreationScripts\**" />
    <None Remove="ReadmeFiles\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
   
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.21.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.21.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Change the web.config handler from AspNetCoreModuleV2 to AspNetCoreModule

Comment: Install the Hosting Bundle from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1)

Comment: Please refer [500.31 ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#50031-ancm-failed-to-find-native-dependencies)